# Play 2.1.2: Jackson does not seem to support @JsonTypeInfo

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Pretty simple scenario here.  I've got:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
class Thing(val id: Int)
```

...

```
class LowerThing(id: Int) extends Thing(id)
```

(I have Json.read and Json.writes defined for both classes, and the necessary apply/unapply methods (which do the straightforward thing - just as if they were case classes.)

In a controller, in a post I have:

```
    request =>
      val thing = request.body.asJson.get.as[Thing]
```

I can post JSON like this:

```
{"@type":"com.foo.LowerThing","id":1}
```

or any other subclass, but Jerkson always gives me a straight Thing back.

Also, when Things are serialized out, @type is not included, making it impossible for the client to instantiate the correct type of object on the other end.

Note that virtually the exact same code works fine with Jackson under a Java EE server.  Even older versions of Jackson.

(I am trying to justify a move to all-Scala & Play from Java EE. For the most part it's gone wonderful but things like this have to be made to work.  It would really be a shame for us to have to handle our own polymorphic JSON serialization - there must be a way to do this but I can't find it easily.  And I'm puzzled as to why this doesn't simply work, as Jackson is Jackson.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to solve the problem, by using the Jackson API directly:

```
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
  val thing = mapper.readValue(request.body.asJson.get.toString, classOf[Thing])
```

It hit me that Play's JSON libraries are probably not using Jackson in a way that I am familiar with - if they were a no-arg ctor would be necessary, instead of the apply/unapply that Json reads/writes make use of.

I don't want to use this mechanism because makes immutable objects difficult or impossible, so I would still appreciate someone demonstrating to me how polymorphic JSON de-serialization can be achieved using Play's JSON library directly.

Comment: Immutability is still possible - you just need the zero-arg ctor.  I would still prefer to use Play's more idiomatic Scala JSON tools.

Comment: Is there really no straightforward way to achieve polymorphic JSON serialization with the Play JSON API?